# Género de las profesionales del modelaje: ¿por qué no se dice "la modela"?

Tags: gramática, género

Escuché de pasada en un programa de televisión a un comentarista hablar de "la model**a**", refiriéndose a una señorita que ejerce el modelaje. Pensé que fue un lapsus, pero no, era sistemático y claramente se trataba de una especie de manifiesto personal acerca de la igualdad de género, como el que se ha dado con tanta frecuencia durante la última década.

En la RAE se dice explícitamente que "modelo" (con "o" final) es un sustantivo masculino y fémenino, lo cual me parece curioso considerando que, al menos a primera vista, el modelaje es una ocupación ejercida principalmente por mujeres.

¿Por que no se hace en este caso la distinción modelo/modela como en el resto de los sustantivos? ¿Hay otros casos en los que la terminación "o" sirva para ambos géneros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> La palabra modelo nos viene del italiano *modello*, durante el Renacimiento (siglo XVI) que surgió en Italia y nos dio artistas como Miguel Ángel, Leonardo Da Vinci y Rafael. (...) La palabra italiana *modello* es un diminutivo de la palabra latina *modus* (manera, medida), que encontramos en varios términos legales como *modus operandi* y *modus vivendi.* ([etimologias.dechile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?modelo))

Con respecto a la profesión, la idea de "modelo" se refiere a un arquetipo. Ello puede interpretarse de distintas maneras: como un "modelo de belleza" que se pretende imitar, como una representación estándar de una pieza de ropa de algún diseñador, etc. El término modelo empezó siendo masculino por congruencia con la palabra latina de la que procede ("modus"). Desde entonces, el género no ha variado.

Algunos otros sustantivos que acaban en -o tanto para el género femenino como el masculino son *miembro, soprano, árbitro, piloto, soldado, sargento<sup>1</sup>, cabo o testigo*, y algunas abreviaciones de profesiones como *fisio* u *otorrino*.

---

<sup>1: Según la RAE, cuando [sargento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XJGE7Vc) se refiere a "suboficial de graduación inmediatamente superior al cabo mayor e inferior al sargento primero", aplica tanto al género femenino como al masculino. La palabra [sargenta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XJ5seWI) también existe, pero significa "alabarda que llevaba el sargento", "coloq. Mujer corpulenta, hombruna y de dura condición" o "coloq. Mujer del sargento".</sup>

Comment: La RAE acepta actualmente el uso de *árbitra* para el femenino y yo lo he oído en alguna ocasión. Pero sé de mujeres que ejercen el arbitraje y prefieren que se las llame *árbitro* por eliminar la referencia al sexo en ese caso concreto; prefieren que se considere al árbitro más una función que una persona. Incluso me contó una amiga, jugadora de rugby, una anécdota interesante. En ese deporte es habitual tratar al árbitro con mucho respeto, llamándole *señor*. Una jugadora se dirigió a la árbitra llamándola *señora* y esta le corrigió: "Si no le importa, *señor*".