# Why do names of professions mostly have the feminine ending -a?

Tags: historia, género

Why are *pediatra, taxista, turista, policía*, etc. used to describe both males and females? It makes less sense when you realize that up to the 1960s, all of these professions were mostly male.

Comment: Hi! I've edited your question to make it clearer. Tangentially related to it, you might want to check out the answers to *[Why do Spanish words have gender?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/why-do-spanish-words-have-gender)*.

Comment: most of feminine words in spanish end in a not just professions. Perro perra (dog bitch) gato gata (male cat- female cat)

Comment: Opposite case: [la modelo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16055/6915)

Answer (score 11):

*Pediatra*, *taxista*, *turista* and *policía* are not feminine but [common gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender_in_Spanish): they are invariable and can function either as masculine or feminine; this will be manifest by the form of the articles, adjectives, etc. that agree with them. What you surely meant to ask was why those words have the ending *-a* which commonly marks feminine gender. In fact it has nothing to do with it.

- *pediatra* has the ending *-atra* which is common to medical specialists and which comes from the same root as *-atría* (as in *pediatría*): the Greek word *[iatrós](http://www.gramaticas.net/2011/01/ejemplos-sufijo-atra-atria.html)* "physician".
- *taxista*, likewise, has the suffix *-ista* which designates occupations as well as political, ideological or esthetic leanings (*comunista*, *reformista*, etc.). This suffix comes from Latin *-ista* and this in turn from Greek. In Latin there were three genders, not two, and final *-a* did not always mark the feminine gender.
- *turista* employs the same suffix as *taxista* (it is actually a calque from English *tourist*).
- *policía* meaning "police" is indeed feminine, as was the Latin word *politīa*, but if the meaning is "police agent" (*un policía hombre, una policía mujer*) it is, like the other examples, an epicene noun. The (feminine) name for the institution came first, and then the name of the agent was derived from it by [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche).

Comment: Epicene is for words that don't allow but only one gender (víctima, persona, ayuda, etc) the ones you are referring its "common gender" and "ambiguos gender" where both masculine and feminine can coexist in different ways.

Comment: @celerno You're absolutely right. I've corrected my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Modista  respondía al mismo esquema que otras profesiones como taxista, el / la taxista. A principios  del siglo pasado nace el uso de palabra modisto para masculino y se reserva modista para femenino. Es una excepción adquirida de -ista  con género neutro.

Comment: Buena respuesta, JPRozas. Bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]. Te recomienda pasarte por el [tour] y [answer] para un resumen de cómo funciona el sitio.